# Wrong keyboard for EditText

Tags: android, xml

I want to input negative decimal numbers into my **EditText**.

So it's my **EditText**:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/test"
    ndroid:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="2"
    android:inputType="numberSigned|numberDecimal" />
```

But look on ***keyboard*** in this case: ***>>>***
[SCREENSHOT](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zlrkkorkiwutlsp/editText%20issue.png)***<<<***

If I press on `.-` **Button** i have only `.`

long push button = the same.

My **EditText** is in:

```
<TabHost  <LinearLayout  <FrameLayout  <RelativeLayout  <TableRow  **EditText**
```

May be problem is related to this...

Comment: Try to push down and wait for a while...

Comment: Then whats wrong with that? Your input type is numberSigned and decimal. So, its correct

Comment: Omg, yeah, that's why I post screenshot with issue.

Comment: the inputType is correct, try to do a double click to - button

Comment: @AT_AB you are right dude! Write this comment as answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: It would be preferable if you add the screenshot into the post instead of a link... ssave us the trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Try this

Your `android:inputType="numberSigned|numberDecimal"` is correct,

try to do a double click to `.-` Button

Comment: Ok, but Button called ".-"

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:digits="-.0123456789"
        android:id="@+id/txtUser"/>
```

It allows you to enter '-' as well '.'

[image: Negative Decimal Keyboard]

This should work.

Comment: It should, but it doesn't. Screen: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wfawbd03vq3ligc/Screenshot_2.png

Answer (score 0):

Amit Gupta answer (and code in your question) is correct for pure AOSP Android version, but I can see from screenshots that you are using Samsung Galaxy S/Note device. Samsung's Android is highly modified (and has it's own keyboard) and that is one of many things that doesn't work as it should. Try this:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:digits="-.0123456789"
    android:id="@+id/txtUser"/>
```

Difference between my answer and Amit Gupta answer is that `inputType` is `phone`, not `number`

Answer (score 0):

Programatically (Kotlin)

```
myEditText?.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER or InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL or InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED
```